# python .xml and .csv files manipulation

Tags: python, xml, csv

I made a conversion from an .xml file to .csv. In the .xml file there were some values ​​from the `txtDescricao` column of this type: `"Logistics, Search and Support."` Because of this, when I read the file, pandas interprets that comma after `Logistics`as a column separator, and throws the rest of the text forward. I am trying to work around this with the following code:

```
in_file = 'dados_limpos_2018.csv'
out_file = 'dados_2018.csv'
output = open(out_file, 'w')
with open(in_file, 'r') as source:
    for line in source:
    # split by semicolon
        data = line.strip().split(';')             
    # remove all quotes found
        data = [t.replace('"','') for t in data]
        for item in data[:-1]:
            item.replace(',', '')
            output.write(''.join(['', item, '',',']))
            # write the last item separately, without the trailing ';'
        output.write(''.join(['"', item, '"']))
        output.write('\n')
output.close()
```

however, in the line python already interprets the comma as separator and turns it into a semicolon. Here I would like to know: Is there any way I can handle this in the .csv file, or would I have to do this in .xml to .csv conversion?
Example of .cs file

```
name, number, sgUF, txtDescricao, year
Romario, 15, RJ, Consultoria, 2018
Ronaldo, 9, RJ, Logistics, Search and Support, 2018
```

Example .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <dados>
          <despesa>
                  <name>Romario</name>
                  <number>15</number>
                  <sgUF>RJ</sgUF>
                  <txtDescricao>Consultoria</txtDescricao>
                  <year>2018</year>
           </despesa>

           <despesa>
                  <name>Ronaldo</name>
                  <number>9</number>
                  <sgUF>RJ</sgUF>
                  <txtDescricao>Logistics, Search and Support</txtDescricao>
                  <year>2018</year>
           </despesa>
     </dados>
</xml>
```

Note: The original file is too large to open in spreadsheet editor.

Comment: Where is your .xml file read in code? Only .csv files are assigned. Also, where is pandas used? What is desired output? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56379100/edit) your post for a [MCVE]. Make sure what you post can fully run (include `import` lines) to reproduce your issues in empty Python environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your function to deal with those cases in the `txtDescricao` column.

```py
ncols= 5
index = 3
in_file = 'dados_limpos_2018.csv'
out_file = 'dados_2018.csv'
output = open(out_file, 'w')
with open(in_file, 'r') as source:
     for line in source:
         # split by colon
         data = line.strip().split(',')
         # Change third element
         data_len = len(data)
         if  data_len > ncols:
             # Join all elements
             data[index] = ''.join(data[index:index + 1 + (data_len - ncols)])
             data[index + 1:] = data[index + 1 + data_len - ncols:]
         # Write columns
         output.write(','.join(data[:ncols]))
         output.write('\n')
 output.close()
```

Input file:

```
name, number, sgUF, txtDescricao, year
Romario, 15, RJ, Consultoria, 2018
Ronaldo, 9, RJ, Logistics, Search and Support, 2018
```

Output file:

```
name, number, sgUF, txtDescricao, year
Romario, 15, RJ, Consultoria, 2018
Ronaldo, 9, RJ, Logistics Search and Support, 2018
```

**OBS.:** I am assuming that this problem only occurs in the `txtDecricao` column.

Comment: why   'if len(data) > 5:' ?

Comment: Check If the row has more than 5 comma-separated values (the number of columns). If this occurs, I am assuming that the values in the `txtDescricao` have commas in it and are producing more than 5 values in the list `data`.

Comment: In the original file, there are 28 columns and the one with the commas is 8. I made the substitutions: 3 in your code represents 8 in mine; 4 => 9; 5 => 10; Still the error persists.

Comment: I fixed the code to a more general case, it should be clearer now.

Comment: Got it. However, you are merging the column names, type: txtDescricaoyear

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you share your xml file.

Based on supplied info,

If your xml file data has `,` as value, use different separator(semicolon,tab,space) to form your csv file.
Or
Just replace `,` with null when its in XML file, then convert.

In both situations, you should handle this while converting from xml to csv. With csv -> csv will be hard to implement and count of , will be unpredictable.

EDIT 1:

I suggest to use objectify from lxml.
Dont forget to delete `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from your xml.
Solution is below.

```
from lxml import objectify
import csv

file_xml = open('d:\\path\\to\\xml.xml','r')
converted_csv_file = open("converted.csv","w")
xml_string = file_xml.read()
xml_object = objectify.fromstring(xml_string)
csvwriter = csv.writer(converted_csv_file, delimiter=',',lineterminator = '\n')
count = 0
for row in xml_object.dados.despesa:
    if count == 0:
        csvwriter.writerow([row.name.tag,row.number.tag,row.sgUF.tag,row.txtDescricao.tag,row.year.tag])
    csvwriter.writerow([row.name.text,row.number.text,row.sgUF.text,row.txtDescricao.text.replace(',',''),row.year.text])
    count += 1
```

You can install lxml by

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: I'm trying this and got the following error:
no such child: name

Comment: Its case sensitive so you have child ‘Name’ or ‘name’ in xml